# PHP get comma separated values which are not enclosed

Tags: php, regex

having string like this :

```
5, "hi all, this is a comma", 'text without comma', 5,'a',',',","
```

i want to break the string into an array, but still there are values which contain commas (enclosed by single OR double quotes)

what's the fastest regex possible (explode won't work here)

i could use `str_getcsv` but the strings are enclosed sometime by single quotes , other times by double quotes ! need something smarter

Comment: Did this come froma file? Then use `fgetcsv()`

Comment: No , it's a user input / socket reciv

Comment: i could use `str_getcsv` but the strings are enclosed sometime by single quotes , other times by double quotes ! need something smarter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a csv parser, or *preg_split* with this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~(?:\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*"|)\K(,|$)~';
```